# Large file dropbox upload APIv2 python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dropbox-api

I'm working on a school project where a camera records a video and then uploads it to Dropbox, sadly I'm having trouble uploading quite large files, the file is about 172Mb.

```
dropboxServer = dropbox.Dropbox(token)
with open(filename,'rb') as file:
    response = dropboxServer.file_upload(file.read(),'/Videos/'+filename)
    print("Upload:"+response)
```

The Error:
https://pastebin.com/W8NS6BeY

Comment: Could you eleborate a bit more? Like do you get an error? If so which one?

Comment: OHHHH, I totally forgot,ill post the error soon, thanks :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your connection timeout before the file is uploaded.

Given by: `socket.timeout: The write operation timed out` from your traceback.

To fix this, you can set (overwrite the default 30 seconds) the timeout when creating the Dropbox object, see more info here: [module-dropbox.dropbox](https://dropbox-sdk-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/moduledoc.html#module-dropbox.dropbox)

Answer (score 0):

Per the documentation for `files_upload`, for large files like this (>150 MB) you should use upload sessions instead:

> Do not use this to upload a file larger than 150 MB. Instead, create an upload session with [`files_upload_session_start()`](https://dropbox-sdk-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/moduledoc.html#dropbox.dropbox.Dropbox.files_upload_session_start).

Answer (score 0):

@chjortlund
Thank you for the help! I really appreciate it :D
All I did was was change the timeout variable in the dropboxServer object

```
dropboxSever._timeout = number
```